# The extended customized stopword arent working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, stop-words

I have created some custom stopwords  and when i am trying to filter the text using the custom stopwords ,not all custom stopwords are being filtered from my text.Do we have any limit as such   to extend the custom stop word.
Example:Python| Stopwords

```
new_stopwords=['always','example','session','etc','uh']

import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stpwrd = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
stpwrd.extend(new_stopwords)

step1=['then', 'insightful', 'so', 'as', 'always,', 'we', 'have', 'two', 'topics', 'for', "today's", 'session', 'uh']

step2=filtered_words = [word for word in step1 if word not in stpwrd]
print(step2)
output:['insightful','always,'topics']
```

The above output still has always in the putput but i am excluded this always word  in my custom stopwords list.Then why is it still coming in the output. I have tried by lowering the complete text first and then passed and also tried the case sensitive but still i see these words being appeared in the output despite of  adding in the stopword  custome list.
Appreciate for your help.

Comment: The exact text string in `step1`  appears to be `always,` - including a comma. This wouldn't get filtered out because `always` is not the same as `always,`.

Comment: Right . i missed. Thanks for the prompt response